# Extrude faces along normals causes twisted quads. Is there a workaround?

Tags: modeling, extrude

[image]

I often find myself extruding faces at these slided angles (because it looks cool ;-) ).
That leads to these twisted sides, which I understand, there is no way to connect all the vertices with planar quads. So far my only workaround is to extrude faces individually and then fill in the gaps myself. Is there maybe some quicker workaround? I also have boxcutter and mesh tools, but haven't used it a lot yet, maybe there is some trick there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This changed in 2.93, but I believe you need at least 2.93.1 for it to work.

You can select the ring of faces and extrude them.  Immediately click to accept the extrusion and go to to the Last Operator panel and select *Dissolve Orthogonal Edges*:

[image: Last Operator panel, showing Dissolve Orthogonal Edges]

Now you can scale the selection and achieve the result you want.

[image: scaled extrusion]

Comment: Thank you, that works quite well! I have to use the knife tool afterwards, but that is a lot less work and the result is exactly what I wanted to achieve.